# Query on filters selected by the user

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ado.net

I am making a job portal where users can search jobs by keywords, job category, location salary range, company name.....and I want that if a user select only one option and start searching then he will get all results that belong to that particular option....and if a user select multiple options then result should be filtered according to that...so here i am unable to query data....I just want that the search should be made only by those parameters which are provided by user...other parameters whose values are not provided should not be a part of searching/ query....

This is a bad sample of what i am thinking to do....This query is just for providing you an idea... This is not correct

```
SELECT        employer.phone, employer.mobile, employer.company, employer.country, employer.state, employer.city, employer.address, jobs.title, jobs.category, jobs.salary, 
                         jobs.skills, jobs.contactPerson, jobs.exper, jobs.email AS Expr1, jobs.jobsummary, jobs.posteddate
FROM            employer INNER JOIN
                         jobs ON employer.id = jobs.empid
WHERE        (jobs.skills LIKE '%' + @keyword + '%') OR
                         (employer.city LIKE '%' + @location + '%') OR
                         (employer.state LIKE '%' + @location + '%')
```

Comment: try something like `(@keyword IS NULL OR job.skills LIKE ....`) and bind a NULL to @keyword if it is not a selected parameter

Answer (score 1):

Use `AND` logic in the where clause and set the unused variables to a blank and everything will work: if `@keywords` is blank, `(jobs.skills LIKE '%%')` will match all `jobs.skills`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach

```
SELECT        employer.phone, employer.mobile, employer.company, employer.country, employer.state, employer.city, employer.address, jobs.title, jobs.category, jobs.salary, 
                         jobs.skills, jobs.contactPerson, jobs.exper, jobs.email AS Expr1, jobs.jobsummary, jobs.posteddate
FROM            employer INNER JOIN
                         jobs ON employer.id = jobs.empid
WHERE        (jobs.skills LIKE '%' + @keyword + '%' OR @keyword is null)
              AND (employer.city LIKE '%' + @location + '%' OR @location is null) 
              AND (employer.state LIKE '%' + @location + '%' OR @location is null)
```

But remember that it can lead to bad execution plan and it can be better to create separate procedures for different variants of search.